# Vim unexpectedly sources javascript indent filetype plugin on editing html files

Tags: html, vim, indentation, vim-plugin, neovim

TL;DR: vim seems to be sourcing both `indent/javascript.vim` and `indent/html.vim` on editing html files; is this intentional or a bug? How can I make html files only source `html.vim`?

---

Recently I found out that vim seems to be using indent filetype plugins for both javascript and html on editing html files, and I've done some testing based on this behaviour on minimal vim configurations.

Here is my one-line `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Inside my `.vim` directory:

```
~ % tree .vim
.vim
└── indent
    ├── html.vim
    └── javascript.vim

1 directory, 2 files
```

Where:

```
~ % cat .vim/indent/javascript.vim
setlocal formatprg=js-beautify
let g:testvar_js="js testvar"
let g:testvar="testvar defined in javascript.vim"
```

and

```
~ % cat .vim/indent/html.vim      
setlocal formatprg=html-beautify
let g:testvar_html="html testvar"
let g:testvar="testvar defined in html.vim"
```

Then I open up a new, empty vim buffer with `vim foo.html`, and tested with some commands:

```
:set filetype?
  filetype=html
:set formatprg?
  formatprg=js-beautify
:echo g:testvar
testvar defined in javascript.vim
:echo g:testvar_html
html testvar
:echo g:testvar_js
js testvar
```

As if vim sources both indent filetype plugins, with `indent/html.vim` first and then `indent/javascript.vim`.

Therefore, my questions are:

- Did I make any silly mistakes?
- If no, then is this an intentional design, a bug, or is that vim has nothing to do with this at all?
- Is there a way to make vim only source on `html.vim` when editing html files?

Some additional information that might be helpful:

- I'm on vim 8.2, macOS arm64, using Terminal.app
- Neovim exhibits the same behaviour; actually that's where I first note it
- This behaviour does not occur for `ftplugin/`, only `indent/`
- javascript files are not affected by `indent/html.vim`: variables defined in `indent/html.vim` are all undefined in a javascript buffer
- `formatprg` of html files is always `js-beautify` on open, regardless of if there are any javascript code pieces or `<script>` tags inside that html file
- An `indent/css.vim` will not be involved at all when editing html - I've tested
- `js-beautify` and `html-beautify` are two separate executables (repository is [here](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify))

  ```
  bin % ls -n js-beautify
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 501  80  53 Apr 19 17:59 js-beautify -> ../lib/node_modules/js-beautify/js/bin/js-beautify.js
  bin % ls -n html-beautify
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 501  80  55 Apr 19 17:59 html-beautify -> ../lib/node_modules/js-beautify/js/bin/html-beautify.js
  ```

If you want me to do some additional tests or need more information, just shout.

Many thanks

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a perfectly valid HTML sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <script>
            console.log('Hello, World!');
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: orange;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample</h1>
    </body>
 </html>
```

You will notice it has a tiny bit of embedded JavaScript in it, which is a good enough reason for `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim` to source `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/javascript.vim`. After  all, the `javascript` indent script is supposed to know how to indent JavaScript, so why not use it in a `html` buffer that *can* contain embedded JavaScript?

FWIW, here is the snippet responsible for that behaviour:

```
if !exists('*GetJavascriptIndent')
  runtime! indent/javascript.vim
endif
```

Note that the maintainers of `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim` chose the external route for `javascript` and the internal one for `css`. Maybe because `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/css.vim` didn't fit the bill? I don't know and, frankly, I don't think it matters.

Now, let's go through your mistakes…

- Filetype-specific scripts (indent, syntax, ftplugins) are sourced in this order:

  1. `~/.vim/indent/<filetype>.vim`,
  2. `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/<filetype>.vim`
  3. `~/.vim/after/indent/<filetype>.vim`

  If you are not very careful, stuff you put in an earlier script might be overwritten when a later script is sourced. For that reason, it makes a lot more sense to put your own stuff in scripts under `after/`.
- The following lines have *nothing* to do in indent scripts:

  ```
  setlocal formatprg=js-beautify
  setlocal formatprg=html-beautify
  ```

  They are supposed to be in ftplugins:

  ```
  " after/ftplugin/javascript.vim
  setlocal formatprg=js-beautify

  " after/ftplugin/html.vim
  setlocal formatprg=html-beautify
  ```

So…

> Did I make any silly mistakes?

Yes, see above.

> If no, then is this an intentional design, a bug, or is that vim has nothing to do with this at all?

Well yes, this is an intentional design that works pretty well. It only caused problems because you misused it.

> Is there a way to make vim only source on `html.vim` when editing html files?

- `indent/html.vim`? Yes, it certainly is possible but why would you want to do that?
- `ftplugin/html.vim`? It already works the way you want and it is the right place for the things you mistakenly put in `indent/html.vim` to begin with.

--- EDIT ---

> Just curious, `indent/` files are supposed to set indentation options right, then why shouldn't I set the indentation program there?

Filetype-specific scripts are typically sourced once, when a file of the corresponding filetype is loaded into a buffer. Because it is relatively common to have languages embedded in other languages (JavaScript in HTML) or languages that are supersets of other languages (C++ vs C), Vim makes it possible to source other filetype-specific scripts. That's pretty much a concrete example of code reuse and that's generally considered a good thing.

Indent scripts can source other indent scripts, syntax scripts can source other syntax scripts, and ftplugins can source other ftplugins.

So Vim gives us a useful low-level mechanism but it is up to us to decide what to put where, and that always depends on the context.

In the case of HTML, it makes sense to use the existing JavaScript indent stuff, so `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim` sources `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/javascript.vim` early on and then proceeds with setting HTML-specific stuff. The end result is a `html` indent script that also supports embedded JavaScript. The `html` syntax script uses a similar mechanism in order to highlight embedded JavaScript. In some simple cases, you can even have one ftplugin sourcing another ftplugin but `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim` doesn't.

But it doesn't *always* makes sense: options may be overwritten, mappings may be overwritten or defined in contexts where they don't make sense, etc. In this specific case, what external tool to use for formatting is highly context-sensitive: you can't really expect `js-beautify` to format HTML properly or `html-beautify` to format JavaScript properly so `formatprg` must be set separately for the `javascript` and `html` filetypes.

ANd this is where your first mistake kicks in.

Here is once again the snippet that sources `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/javascript.vim` from `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim`:

```
if !exists('*GetJavascriptIndent')
  runtime! indent/javascript.vim
endif
```

`:help :runtime` is a smart alternative to `:help :source` that looks for files in `:help 'runtimepath'`. Because your `~/.vim/indent/javascript.vim` is in your `runtimepath`, it will be sourced. Because there is a `!`, every matching file is going to be sourced. Because it comes first in `runtimepath`, it might be overwritten by later scripts.

In your case, `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/html.vim` automatically sources your `~/.vim/indent/javascript.vim`, which contains stuff that shouldn't be set in a `html` buffer.

The `after` directory allows you to have the last word on what is set for a given filetype because built-in scripts rarely, if ever, do `runtime! after/indent/<filetype>.vim`

That explains why it is a bad idea to carelessly put your filetype-specific stuff in `~/.vim/{ftplugin,indent,syntax}/` and why you should put it in `~/.vim/after/{ftplugin,indent,syntax}/` instead.

Comment: Much thanks. Just curious, `indent/` files are supposed to set indentation options right, then why shouldn't I set the indentation program there?

Comment: Please, see my edit.